# NullPointer with a Bluetooth communication with a few fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

For a project for school, I have to create an application for Android and I am not an expert in Android. I have to transfert data from a smartphone to another. I need a couple fragment to do that, the first one his the page where I can search and pair a device and start the communication. The second one has a button that send data to the other smartphone. To learn how to use the Bluetooth, I followed a tutorial to create a chat but everything is on the same view so I tried to split the code to create my fragments and I have an error with NullPointerException (I know that some people already had an error like that but I tried their solution and I didn't work).

This is the code for the first fragment:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.bertrand.test_v1.Models.BluetoothConnectionService;
import com.bertrand.test_v1.Models.DeviceListAdapter;
import com.bertrand.test_v1.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ConnectionFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConnectionFragment";
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString("00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices;
    public Set<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceBonded;
    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;

    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;
    ListView lvDevices;
    Button btnStartConnection;
    Button btnSearch;
    StringBuilder message;

    public static ConnectionFragment newInstance() {
        return (new ConnectionFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connection, container, false);

        mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        mDeviceBonded = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        lvDevices = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_devices);

        for (BluetoothDevice bt : mDeviceBonded)
        {
            mBTDevices.add(bt);
        }

        mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.device_adapteur_view, mBTDevices);
        lvDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiverBound, filter);
        lvDevices.setOnItemClickListener(ConnectionFragment.this);

        btnStartConnection = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_connect_btn_start);
        btnStartConnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startConnection();
            }
        });

        btnSearch = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_connect_btn_search);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices...");

                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

                    //Check BT permissions in manifest
                    checkBTPermissions();

                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiverDiscover, discoverDevicesIntent);
                }
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    //Check BT permissions in manifest
                    checkBTPermissions();

                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiverDiscover, discoverDevicesIntent);
                }
            }
        });

        message = new StringBuilder();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("incomingMessage"));

        return rootView;
    }


    public void startBTConnection(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection");

        mBluetoothConnection.startClient(device, uuid);
    }

    //Remember the connection will fail and app will crash if you haven't paired first
    public void startConnection()
    {
        startBTConnection(mBTDevice, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
    }

    /*
        Discover new devices.
        This broadcast receiver is use for listening devices that are not yet paired.
     */

    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiverDiscover = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "onReciver: ACTION FOUND.");

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + " : " + device.getAddress());

                int i = 0;
                for (; i < mBTDevices.size(); i++) {
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress())) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i == mBTDevices.size()) {
                    mBTDevices.add(device);
                }

                mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapteur_view, mBTDevices);
                lvDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
            }
        }
    };

    /*
        Bounding devices.
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiverBound = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Case 1: bounded already
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");

                    mBTDevice = mDevice;
                }
                // Case 2: creating a bone
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
                }
                // Case 3: breaking a bond
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("theMessage");

            message.append(text + "\n");
        }
    };

    /*
        Check permissions method.
        This method is required for all devices running API23+.
        Android must programmatically check the permissions for Bluetooth.
        Putting the proper permissions in the manifest is not enough.

        NOTE: This will only execute on version >LOLLIPOP because it is not needed otherwise.
     */
    public void checkBTPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            int permissionCheck = this.getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += this.getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {
                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }

    /*
        Bounding device - item click
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //First cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + deviceAddress);

        //Create the bond
        //NOTE: Requires API 17+
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();

            mBTDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);
            mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(getActivity());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the second fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.bertrand.test_v1.Controllers.Activities.MainActivity;
import com.bertrand.test_v1.Models.BluetoothConnectionService;
import com.bertrand.test_v1.R;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;

public class SendFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString("00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    Button btnSend;
    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
    ConnectionFragment dev;
    MainActivity sendData;
    BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;

    public static SendFragment newInstance()
    {
        return (new SendFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);

        btnSend = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_send_btn_send);
        try
        {
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothConnection.mmDevice;
            Log.d("Send", device.getName());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String msg = "bp_send";
                byte[] bytes = msg.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                try
                {
                    mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is the error that I have:

```
03-19 14:44:37.940 17888-17888/com.bertrand.test_v1 W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 14:44:37.950 17888-17888/com.bertrand.test_v1 W/System.err:     at com.bertrand.test_v1.Controllers.Fragments.SendFragment$1.onClick(SendFragment.java:62)
```

Thank you for your help.

Bertrand.

Comment: I believe the `mBluetoothConnection` is not initialized in your second fragment.

Comment: Yes but when I try to get the name and the address of the device that I paired in the first fragment, I see that there are empty. So I thing that when I close the first fragment everything about the connection is erase, but in the Raspberry the connection is still on.

Comment: I hope you should initialize this in the parent activity which holds the fragment and use the same instance in your fragments.